# The files served by my Apache Server are not being saved on browser cache

Tags: apache, google-chrome, caching

I have installed and configured an Apache server with a virtualhost which serves images.

When I load my page with images on the browser the second time (the images should be on cache after the first time the page is loaded), the browser doesnt get the images (or files) from cache, and think that it should.

What is wrong? I am using Google Chrome, and when I load some other web from other server the cache works, so I think that I have some problem with the Apache, but I am not sure.

Thank you very much.

The response is a video-segment which is played by Dash player.

Response headers:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
content-length:194431
date:Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:42:07 GMT
etag:"2f77f-52acd33f8b167"
last-modified:Tue, 02 Feb 2016 17:55:12 GMT
server:Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.2
status:200
```

After doing that:

```
ExpiresActive On

# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|m4s)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3600 seconds"
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Content-Type "video/mp4"
Header set Vary "Host"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

The headers are:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:public
content-length:194431
content-type:video/mp4
```

But it doesnt save on the cache, I mean, when I reload the web or the video, it does not get it from the cache as it should.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTTP Headers returned when requesting your images or this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved the problem.

I was using an https connection and the certificate I was using didnt have the correct parameters (common name must be the name of the url programmed on the server) and the certificate of the server must be authenticate by some CA, so I have made CA certificates to authenticate the server certificates. This means that if you have an unsecure https connection, Chrome does not save files on cache.

After having all the certificates corrected, I have upload to google chrome the certificates to trust my web (configuration of google Chrome, advanced options, Manage https/ssl certificates). After that, I can save files on cache because of the certificates which makes the https connection secure (green lock on the chrome url bar).

That was my problem and this is how I solved it.

Thanks for your answers and your time!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not including any cache-control headers telling the browser to cache the resources. The spec is unclear how to handle this but most browsers choose not to cache unless explicitly told to.

You need to include Apache config like this (assuming you are already including the mod_expiries module):

```
ExpiresActive On

# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<filesMatch ".([iI][cC][oO]|[gG][iI][fF]|[jJ][pP][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|[fF][lL][vV]|[pP][dD][fF]|[sS][wW][fF]|[mM][oO][vV]|[mM][pP]3|[wW][mM][vV]|[pP][pP][tT])$">
   ExpiresDefault A604800
   Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

# Set up caching on font files for 6 months
<filesMatch ".([eE][oO][tT]|[tT][tT][fF]|[sS][vV][gG]|[Ww][Oo][Ff][Ff]|[Ww][Oo][Ff][Ff]2)$">
   ExpiresDefault 15552000
   Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
```

Which will then produce a header like this:

```
cache-control:max-age=10800, public
```

I've written a blog post on this if you want more details: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http-performance-headers/caching/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not able to reach my aim of save files on cache, as I say on the question (I have written more things there). Thanks for your help!!!